# Mod Rewrite RewriteMap Regex - Search Parameters

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write mod rewrite redirects using rewritemap but am having trouble with my regex. I need to isolate each search parameter in my old URL, and map it into its corresponding query parameter. My plan is to have three separate rules depending on if the user has 1, 2, or 3 search parameters. I am currently trying to write the regex for if the user has 1 search parameter, but am having trouble doing so.

Regex: `/store/search/([^/]*)^((?!/).)`

In addition, I am wondering how I am able to re-use my map when the user has entered multiple search parameters.

```
# Desired redirects:
http://www.my-host.com/store/search/small => http://www.my-host.com/store/search?q=tall
http://www.my-host.com/store/search/medium/low-calorie => http://www.my-host.com/store/search?q=grande,healthy
http://www.my-host.com/store/search/medium/low-calorie/brown => http://www.my-host.com/store/search?q=grande,healthy,chocolate

RewriteMap searchMap txt:/opt/etc/apache/conf/searchMap.txt
RewriteCond ${searchMap:$1|$1} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule "/store/search/([^/]*)^((?!/).)" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/store/search?q=%1" [NC,R,L]

# searchMap.txt
small tall
medium grande
low-fat healthy
low-calorie healthy
brown chocolate
pink strawberry
```

Comment: `/small` will go for `q=tall`? :P

Comment: @hjpotter92 `small` => `tall`

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex I should be using is:

```
/store/search/([^/]*)$
/store/search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
/store/search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
```

Comment: More _specific_ regex should appear first in `RewriteRule`s

Comment: Do you mean that I have them in the reverse order?

Comment: Wouldn't `$` address this? On a separate note, I'm trying to figure out multiple mappings and have created a separate thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398815/mod-rewrite-multiple-rewritemap-lookup