# Mod Rewrite Not Performing Multiple RewriteMap Lookups

Tags: mod-rewrite

My Rewrite rule is not performing multiple rewritemap lookups and I am confused why. I am trying to redirect my users to a new URL search structure. The rewrite rule does not work when there are multiple search parameters and I am unsure why.

```
// Desired mapping examples:
http://www.host.com/search/small         => http://www.host.com/search?q=tall
http://www.host.com/search/medium/brown  => http://www.host.com/search?q=grande,chocolate

// Rule
RewriteMap searchMap txt:/opt/etc/apache/conf/searchMap.txt

// 1 Search Parameter
RewriteCond ${searchMap:$1|$1} ([^/]*)
RewriteRule "/search/(([^/]*))$" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?q=%1" [NC,R,L]

// 2 Search Parameter
RewriteCond ${searchMap:$1|$1} ([^/]*)/([^/]*)
RewriteRule "/search/(([^/]*)/([^/]*))$" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?q=%1,%2" [NC,R,L]

// 3 Search Parameter
RewriteCond ${searchMap:$1|$1} ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)
RewriteRule "/search/(([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*))$" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?q=%1,%2,%3" [NC,R,L]

// searchMap.txt
small tall
medium grande
low-fat healthy
low-calorie healthy
brown chocolate
pink strawberry
```

Output:

```
http://www.host.com/search/small         => http://www.host.com/search?q=tall
http://www.host.com/search/small/brown   => http://www.host.com/search?q=small,brown
```

My first output is being mapped correctly, but my second one is not. Apache has not performed any mapping. Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to put the mapping lookup within the Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteMap searchMap txt:/opt/etc/apache/conf/searchMap.txt
RewriteRule "/search/(([^/]*))$" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?q=${searchMap:$1|$1}" [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule "/search/(([^/]*)/([^/]*))$" "http://%{HTTP_HOST}/search?q=${searchMap:$1|$1},${searchMap:$2|$2}" [NC,R,L]
```